# Unable to build .exe from Python program which uses pandas

Tags: pandas, python-3.4, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I'm using pyinstaller to build a standalone executable.  Pyinstaller successfully makes the executable, but when I run the .exe I get the following error:

> ImportError: C extension: 'lib' not built.  If you want to import
>   pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.

In my attempts to solve the problem, I went looking for a 'setup.py' file in C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pandas, but did not find one there.  I also uninstalled pandas using pip, then reinstalled from the .whl file from [www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).  I also googled the error, and found someone who seemed to have a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563244/trouble-running-panda-library-in-python).  In that case, the problem was solved by running 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' but again, I can't find setup.py in the pandas directory.  I also found a suggestion to "just use Linux" but that is not an option since this is for work.  I also tried building the executable using py2exe and cx_freeze, but neither of those worked.

I'm using Python 3.4 under Windows 7, and the program runs correctly when I run it from inside PyCharm.  How do I get a working standalone .exe?

Edit:

After to building the executable with py2exe and running it, the error I get is:

> ImportError: (DLL load failed: the specified module could not be
>   found.)
>   'C:\Users\aarjad\PycharmProjects\MyProgram\dist\scipi.special._ufuncs.pyd')

However, 'scipi.special._ufuncs.pyd' is right there in that folder, so I don't know what could be going on there.

After building the executable with cx_freeze and running it, the error I get is:

> ImportError: Error importing scipi: you cannot import scipi while
>   being in the scipi source directory; please exit teh scipy source tree
>   first, then relaunch your python interpreter.

Comment: you need to add additional library files to the `datas` entry of the `program.spec` file ... I dont think pyinstaller has very good python3 support yet ( may also be part of the problem) ... also look into pyinstaller "hooks" as there already probably is a pandas one ...\

Comment: Pandas is supposed to be able to work out of the box as per PyInstaller's "supported packages" page, so no hook should be needed.

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages

Comment: hmmm ... well it works fine in python 2 so see my second point ... since it clearly doesnt work in python3 "out of the box" you must need to add some hooks ...

Comment: I did some googling, couldn't find a hook for pandas.  :/

Comment: sorry ... my first comment provides the information that should help it to work ... but I am not planning on installing python3.4 so I will exit this conversation in the hopes that someone who is familliar with 3.4 and pyinstaller will come along to provide you with additional insight

Comment: Actually, I'm seeing the same problem with pyinstaller under python 2.7, so I don't think it's specific to 3. I will try to install pandas from source to see if @AlexArjad's solution works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by porting the lowess function from the statsmodels package from cython to python, thus removing the need to import the statsmodels package, which is what pyinstaller was choking on.

Comment: Can you explain how you did this, as I have the problem with 3.5 at the moment, thank you